# Add Javascript syntax highlighting to the HAML TM Bundle

Tags: javascript, textmate, haml, textmatebundles

I have the HAML TextMate bundle and inside of the :javascript block, I'd like to have proper javascript syntax highlighting. How could I modify the HAML bundle to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the grammar of the HAML bundle, but it looks like this has already been done in some other forks of the HAML bundle. See [phuibonhoa / handcrafted-haml-textmate-bundle](https://github.com/phuibonhoa/handcrafted-haml-textmate-bundle), for instance:

> Improved Language
>
> - Text inside Ruby, ERB, Javascript, Sass, and CSS filters are now properly recognized so you get all the syntax highlighting, snippets, commands, etc.

Give that fork a shot.

Comment: The syntax highlighting doesn't seem to work for me.  Did you have any luck with it?

Answer (score 0):

this project also has javascript highlighting: https://github.com/mattpolito/ruby-haml.tmbundle

but you'll need the jquery bundle installed as well: https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-tmbundle